# delay router.get till getData Function retrieve information from the API

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am new to node.js and express, so I would like to know what i am doing wrong.
I post the query from the client using $.post and receive it using .post

however the page "/books", which is called using router.get seems to be loaded before the .post finish. after debugging the code, I found that the .post finish

```
let incomingRequest;
let bookTitle = [];
let bookAuthors = [];
let bookSmallThumbnail = [];

router.post('/data/books', function (req, res) {
    incomingRequest = req.body.book;
    console.log(incomingRequest);
});

function getData(cb) {
    request({
            url: `https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=${incomingRequest}`,
            json: true,
        },
        console.log('passed Request'),
        function (error, response, body) {
            if (response.statusCode === 200) {
                cb(body);
            }
            body.items.forEach(item => {
                    bookTitle = bookTitle.concat(item.volumeInfo.title);
                    bookAuthors = bookAuthors.concat(item.volumeInfo.authors);
                    if (item.volumeInfo.imageLinks !== undefined && item.volumeInfo.imageLinks !== null) {
                        bookSmallThumbnail = bookSmallThumbnail.concat(item.volumeInfo.imageLinks.smallThumbnai);
                    }
                })
        });

}

module.exports = {
    getData: getData
}

router.get('/books',function (req, res) {
    getData(function getData(books) {
        res.render(path.join(__dirname, '../Client/books'), {
            bookTitle: bookTitle,
            bookAuthors: bookAuthors,
            bookSmallThumbnail: bookSmallThumbnail
        });
    })
})
```

first and then the .get execute. but every time i query new book the page/books load first and no result unless i refresh the page then the data shows.

i am using ejs to show the return data

here is snippiest from my code:

Comment: the best approach would be to use Promises. Check out this [module](https://github.com/request/request-promise)